Is it possible to program Ardupilot motors individually?
I want to program my drone (Pixhawk 6x, Ardupilot), such that the motors can turn in pairs and reverse in pairs when the flight mode is changed.
For example, in a normal flight mode where all props rotate to lift, if I switch the mode I want two of the props to reverse and the other two to turn off.
Very similar to turtle mode, where all props are reversed, but with individual control over the props' state (running, stopped), direction (lift, reverse) and speed.
The Ardupilot docs for Turtle Model state that only adjacent motors would spin, and that doesn't suffice in my case
https://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/turtle-mode.html
